# "Was to have" expression

Tags: meaning

In 1958, Evans joined Miles Davis's sextet, where he was to have a profound influence.

What is the meaning of "was to have" here?

Comment: He had an influence on the sextet, but at the time he joined it that influence was still in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A) DEFINITION**

The form [*subject - be - to - verb (something)*] is a (i) periphrastic modal, (ii) subject-to-subject raising structure, (iii) expressing deontic modality (in the past futurity), (iv) with formal connotions.

(i) **Periphrastic** modal forms are multi-word analogues of modal verbs. For example, *can* is close in meaning to *be able to*, *must* can often be paraphrased as *have to* (and in fact for the past form only *had to* is available), *may* can usually be replaced by *be allowed to*, etc. The modals *shall*, *should* or *ought to* can frequently be substituted by the structure under discussion, *be to + verb*.

> (1) *You are to come* ≈ *You ought to come*, etc.

(ii) **Subject-to-subject** raising means that the subject of *be* is also understood as the subject of the verb after *to*. To represent this, linguists sometimes use an index such as <sub>i</sub> on the subject and the letter *t* (for trace) with the same index in a position where it is understood or interpreted as well.

> (2) Johnny<sub>i</sub> is [ *t*<sub>i</sub> to do his homework first ]. 
>   --> The subject of *be*, Johnny, is the subject of *do*, i.e. the person who is supoosed to do the homework.

This contrasts with object-to-subject raising, where the subject of *be* is understood to be the object of the verb after *to*.

> (3) Johnny<sub>i</sub> is [ to blame *t*<sub>i</sub> for the crime ].
>   --> The subject of *be*, Johnny, is the object of *blame*, i.e. someone blames him for the crime.

(iii) **Deontic** modality is about permission, obligation, requirements, social rules, ethics, what is right and wrong. The expression *be to + verb* carries such meaning. It can be paraphrased as 'be supposed to do', 'be strongly expected to do', 'be ordered to do', 'be required to do', 'must', 'have to'. Additionally, in the past, it can also mean 'be destined to do', 'be expected to do', 'be going to do', 'shall', 'will.' That's because it's difficult to distinguish between an obligation in the past, and just a task one was going to do in the past.

> (4) a. You are to do the dishes before you meet your friends!
>   --> obligation
>            b.  John was to do the dishes.
>   --> obligation ('had to do the dishes'), but also futurity ('was going to do the dishes')

(iv) **Formal** connotations means that the expression is more common in serious writing than in colloquial spoken conversations. The form sounds a bit stilted, high-brow, archaic, educated or posh, etc.

**B) APPLICATION**

The sentence *He was to have a profound influence* meets the four defining characteristics outlined above as follows.

(i) It is a periphrastic form for a modal, a past form of *shall* or *will*.

> (5) He was to have a profound influence. ≈ He would / should / was going to have a profound influence.

(ii) The subject of *was* is also the subject of *have*.

> (6) He<sub>i</sub> was [*t*<sub>i</sub> to have a profound influence ].

(iii) The meaning is *deontic* at its core but since the verb *be* is in the past, speakers interpret by extension a futurity in the past.

> (7) He was to have a profound influence.
>   --> obligation 'was expected, with extension to futurity 'was destined, was going to'

(iv) Finally, the sentence sounds quite formal. It would be appropriate in an elegant setting, for an educated, higher-class audience. It suggests a certain posh, upper-class, fine-arts, sophisticated context.

Comment: Remark.  When English learners ask a grammar question here at ELU, they may get an answer like this.  Asking instead at https://ell.stackexchange.com may yield a more down-to-earth answer.

Answer (score 1):

The construction *to be* + *infinitive* is one of the ways English expresses future aspect, especially when plans, schedules, or directives dictate the action. In the past tense, it can, as in your example, describe a known outcome as viewed as future from some point in the past, in this case, from 1958.  The same meaning could be conveyed by:

> In 1958, Evans joined Miles Davis's sextet, where he *would* have a profound influence.
>   In 1958, Evans joined Miles Davis's sextet, where he *was going to* have a profound influence.

The same notion of time informs this sentence about building a railway:

> The Pacific railway *was to be* a government project, but it [*was to be built*](https://books.google.de/books?id=_ogUAQAAIAAJ&q=%22was+to+be+built%22&dq=%22was+to+be+built%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjStZvH573hAhVDwqYKHbOHDYIQ6AEITzAH) by private companies supported by government aid. — *Encyclopedia of North American Railroads*, 2007, 796.

Railway construction was planned and executed as a public-private partnership. Narrative time lies before the construction took place.

In the present tense, the construction can have the force of an imperative with no particular anchor to time, especially in formulating rules, regulations, or directives, for instance, in these sentences excerpted from rules governing construction sites in an Oklahoma town:

> Sand, mud, and debris that enter the roadway *are to be immediately cleaned up* and placed back onto the construction site.
>   Maintain an on-site receptacle for depositing trash and debris. The receptacle [*is to be*](https://www.jenks.com/sites/default/files/forms/Bldg%20Inspection%20Requirements%20040618.pdf) at a standard capable of restricting trash and debris from blowing onto adjacent properties.
>   Trash and debris *is to be cleaned* daily, contained on-site and disposed of in a waste receptacle to prevent wind or rain from carrying it off-site into a storm drain or waterway.
>   A copy of the permit and temporary address sign indicating the street number *are to be posted* in the front of the property near the street or road. These are to be clearly visible and maintained for the duration of the construction period. — Building Permit Requirements, City of Jenks (OK), 26 Mar. 2018.

This construction can also be used when a planned event does not take place:

> The atmosphere inside a coating tank was tested and ventilated the day before work [*was to be
>   performed*.](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22be%20performed%22;id=mdp.39015060793570;view=image;seq=6;start=1;sz=10;page=root;size=100;orient=0) — U.S. Chemical Safety and Hazard Investigation Board, *Hazards of Nitrogen Asphyxiation*, June 2003.

Work on the tank was scheduled on the day after testing and ventilation, but there was a fatal accident, so the work was not performed as scheduled.

> Last week, Warner Bros. canceled a town hall scheduled for March 15 that was [*to have been led*](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/kevin-tsujiharas-exit-sets-race-top-warner-bros-job-1195554) by Tsujihara in something of a victory lap after his recent promotion. The move was so abrupt that flyers for the event still could be found on the Burbank lot a day before it [*was to have taken place*](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/kevin-tsujiharas-exit-sets-race-top-warner-bros-job-1195554). The town hall has since been rescheduled for April. — *Hollywood Reporter*, 18 Mar. 2019.

In this sentence, the perfect infinitive (*to have been led, to have taken place*) accentuates on 18 Mar. the recent past of 15 Mar., when a planned event didn’t happen but would have had not other forces intervened. The executive was fired for trying to get parts for an actress with whom he had been having an affair.

Answer (score 1):

Quirk et al. in *A Comprehensive Grammar Of The English Language* (p141) list *BE to* as one four *modal idioms*, multi-word verbs that also include *had better*, *would rather* and *have got to*:

> (d) *BE to* is an idiom expressing futurity, with various connotations
>   of 'compulsion', 'plan', 'destiny', etc, according to context. In the
>   past *was to* and *were to* express futurity from the standpoint of
>   past time orientation.

So "*In 1958, Evans joined Miles Davis's sextet, where he was to have a profound influence*" can be understood simply as:

- In 1958, Evans joined Miles Davis's sextet, where he had a profound influence.

Alternatively, you could write:

- In 1958, Evans joined Miles Davis's sextet, where he would (go on to) have a profound influence

or

- In 1958, Evans joined Miles Davis's sextet, where he was going to have a profound influence.